# how can I find the button of my activity in fragment

Tags: android

Just started learning android. Help please. I have three fragments, each has a button that must run one of the streams of the media player. How can I find the button of my activity in the fragment that would later attach to it a specific stream?
Tried to make a reference to the button so that:

```
btnStart = (Button) titleAdapter.frags[0].getView().findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
```

Did not work, an error java.lang.NullPointerException, what I'm doing wrong

```
public class TitleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final String titles[] = new String[] { "FragA", "FragB", "FragC" };
    private final Fragment frags[] = new Fragment[titles.length];
    public TitleAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        frags[0] = new FragmentA();
        frags[1] = new FragmentB();
        frags[2] = new FragmentC();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getPageTitle=", titles[position]);
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("TitleAdapter - getItem=", String.valueOf(position));
        return frags[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return frags.length;
    }
}
```

**code MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  final static String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
  static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  static AudioManager am;
  static CheckBox pdaStream;
  static Button btnNews;
  ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


    TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    pdaStream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pdaStream);
    am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    SeekBar music = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    initBar(music, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);



}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.news:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RSSActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public static void initBar(SeekBar bar, final int stream) {
      bar.setMax(am.getStreamMaxVolume(stream));
      bar.setProgress(am.getStreamVolume(stream));

      bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
          am.setStreamVolume(stream, progress,
                              AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
          // no-op
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
          // no-op
        }
      });
    }
```

}

code fragments similar, here's one of them

**code FragmentA.java:**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

  final static String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";  
  private static ProgressBar progressBar;
      static CheckBox pdaStream;



    public FragmentA() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    final Button Play = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pdaStream = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pdaStream);

       return rootView;
    }   }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_pager"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/pdaStream"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:text="@string/chkbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:background="@drawable/play_button"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add some code with the buttons of your Activity and the Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

You can access like this, for example you want access to button of fragment frags[1]:

```
Button btnFragment = frags[1].getView().findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID);
```

hope it helps!

Comment: add in onCreate (Bundle), Button btnStart = frags[0].getView().findViewById(R.id.btnStart); writes "frags cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Button btnStart = (Button) titleAdapter.frags[0].getView().findViewById(R.id.btnStart); corrected, but when I run error java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a reference from your Activity to the Fragments. As you are creating the Fragments from your PagerAdapter, it has to have the reference as well. You can do this either in the constructor (new Fragment(Activity a)) or by a public variable Activity that you initalize from the activity after creating the PagerAdapter.

in the Activity:

```
 x = new TitleAdapter();
 x.mActivity = this; (while mActivity must be declared public in the TitleAdapter()
```

in the Adapter:

```
frags[0] = new FragmentA();
frags[0].mActivity = this.mActivity;
```

Then in your Fragment you can add a OnClickListener to your button.